# keras target_size and PIL resize inconsistency issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

do anyone have idea why the two outputs below are different

in 1st code block image is loaded and PIL resize used. while in 2nd block keras load_img parameter: target_size is used. for same steps it is giving different output.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img 
import numpy as np
path = 'C:/Users/user/Downloads/random_colour_image.JPG' # actual snippet of image:https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1523270.jpg
target_size = (3,3)

#code block 1
image = load_img(path)
image = image.resize(target_size)
image = np.asarray(image)
print(image)
```

Output 1:

```
[[[132  99  79]
  [146  80  68]
  [165  15  81]]

 [[116 102  94]
  [133 101  69]
  [198  28  53]]

 [[ 82 129 108]
  [119  89 112]
  [166  87  51]]]
```

code block 2:

```
image = load_img(path, target_size=target_size)
image = np.asarray(image)
print(image)
```

Output 2:

```
[[[ 48 190  88]
  [ 57 159  49]
  [145   0  77]]

 [[116  90 101]
  [ 14 133  67]
  [146  19   2]]

 [[  5 119  50]
  [129  69  97]
  [179  63   2]]]
```

Comment: I don't see any PIL module being imported or PIL code, yet you have tagged as `PIL`?

Comment: I'm betting on interpolation methods.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, because Keras uses PIL for image operations and load_image return PIL image object/type. Also the resize method is that of PIL(even though PIL not imported/used explicitly)

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I am unfamiliar with Keras.

Answer (score 0):

thanks I'mahdi. but target_size is also intended to load an resized image. 
 got the solution:
Keras load_img default interpolation is NEAREST(0) and that of PIL.resize is BICUBIC(3). hence that ambiguity.

change in code block 1:

```
image = image.resize(target_size, resample=0)
```

or change in code block 2:

```
image = load_img(path1, target_size=target_size, interpolation='bicubic')
```

will solve it and produce same result. 
Thanks.